# Using toString Method instead of Print method

Tags: java, tostring

How can I use the `toString` method, instead of my custom `print` method below, in my code? My current code's output is exactly what it is supposed to be, but my instructor wants me "*to use `toString` and get same output*". I am confused and do not know how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
public class LinkedListIntro {

    //print method 
    public static void print(Node temp) {
        System.out.print("[");
        while (temp.getNext() != null) {
            System.out.print(temp.getData() + ", ");
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println(temp.getData() + "]");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node start = null;
        Node temp = null;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            if (start == null) {
                start = new Node(i);
                temp = start;
            } else {
                temp.setNext(new Node(i));
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
        }

        //3. printing data
        print(start);

        //4. removing 4  
        temp = start;
        Node n = temp.getNext();

        while (n.getNext() != null) {
            if ((int) n.getData() == 4) {
                temp.setNext(n.getNext());
                n = null;
                break;
            }
            temp = temp.getNext();
            n = n.getNext();
        }

        //5. printing data again after removing 4
        print(start);

        //6. adding 100 between 1 and 2  
        temp = start;
        Node n1 = temp.getNext();

        while (n1.getNext() != null) {
            if ((int) temp.getData() == 1) {
                temp.setNext(new Node(100));
                temp = temp.getNext();
                temp.setNext(n1);
            }
            temp = temp.getNext();
            n1 = n1.getNext();
        }

        //7. printing data again after adding 100
        print(start);

        //8. removing first node
        temp = start;
        start = start.getNext();
        temp = null;

        //printing data after removing 1st node
        print(start);

        //9. add 0 to beginning
        temp = start;
        start = new Node(0);
        start.setNext(temp);

        //printing the final data
        print(start);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Node<E>
{

        private E data;
        private Node next;

        public Node(E data) {
           this.data = data;
           this.next = null;
        }

        public E getData(){
            return data;
        }

        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node next) {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return data.toString();
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use `toString`?

Comment: Please consider indenting your code for legibility. That's a mess.

Comment: No, I am not very familiar with toString method. I actually tried several times, but it did not work, so I just gave up.

Comment: I will take care of indenting. I am a java beginner! Do not expect me a professional code!!

Comment: *"but it did not work"* Tell us what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code in you current `print` method to build an output string in `toString()` method of `Node`. After that, `print` can just pass the `Node temp` parameter to `System.out.print()`, cause it uses `toString()` internally.

```
public static void print(Node temp) { //irrelevant method by now
   System.out.print(temp); 
}

public class Node<E>{

    private E data;
    private Node next;

    //...

    public String toString() {
       String ouput = "";
       Node node = this;
       while(node.getNext() != null) {
          output +=  node.getData() +", ";
          node = node.getNext();
       }
       return ouput; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The toString() methods returns a "string representation" of the object, which means that it returns information about an object as a string.  toString() is overridden by the each class that implements it.  The global superclass (Object) has a .toString() method but it usually doesn't return the information we want.  I think he wants you to make your own toString() that returns a string representation of the Node object.  Then you can call System.out.print() on this string to display it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a toString method which returns a string in LinkedListIntro class which would do what your print method is doing. But instead of printing it would keep appending the value to a string and return the string

Answer (score 0):

I believe what your instructor means is that in the class's `toString()`, you have to return a string for the **entire** linked list, not just for the current node.

The trick is that to do it properly, you'll probably need to do it either recursively or with a helper variable. You'll basically need to prepend the current item's `data`'s `toString()` result to whatever you get from `next`.

Once you do that, you won't need the `print` function.

Comment: Aaaack.  A "node" is not a "list".  If the instructor really wants `toString()` for a `Node` to return a representation of an entire list, he's teaching his students badly.  I'm not saying you're wrong, maybe that _is_ what he really wants.  "Those that can't do, teach..."--I've seen too many examples of that here.

Comment: I think the instructor is asking that the `LinkedListIntro.print()` be replaced with (non-static) `LinkedListIntro.toString()` and that the actual printing to the console (or wherever) would be done outside of the `LinkedListIntro` class.  That would be the 'proper' way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your instructor wants you to implement the method toString() in your class. 
Every class your create is children of Object class, since this is the superclass for every object. This class has some methods like toString(). In your new class, you should override the method toString(). This method must return a String, which should be a description or some helpfull text about every object of this class.
The purpose of this is that if your new class is cast as Object, when you call the toString() method, it gets the right representation of the new class.

You have a class:

```
public class SomeClass {
   public String text;

   public SomeClass() {
      text = "hello world";
   }

   @Override public String toString() {
      return (text);
   }
}
```

And in your main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
   //new object of type SomeClass
   SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
   System.out.println(someClass.toString());
   //casting it to superclass Object
   Object someClass_cast = (Object)someClass;
   System.out.println(someClass_cast.toString());
}
```

Your output will be:

```
hello world
hello world
```

I hope this can help you.